# DiskPart Align Minimum Value

Tags: windows, partitioning, alignment, diskpart

Typically, when the create partition command is invoked, there's a default alignment of 1024, at least for the Windows 7 version. Say these commands were issued.

```
select disk 0
clean
convert gpt
create partition efi size=40 offset=1024
format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
create partition primary
format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows"
```

When I checked for the alignment of the "Windows" partition, it said the offset was 41984kb. However, is it possible to have an align of zero like so?

```
create partition primary align=0
```

Then, I'd save an extra megabyte of space and have an offset of 40960, which is still divisible by 1024, making it still optimal for Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would be able to change the offset to 0 and therefore let the first partition start at sector 0 where do you want to write the partition table?

hence: No, you can't use offset 0.

Comment: You can't do it with the built-in tools, but Windows does recognize a file system at sector 0 if you create it manually.